# Gphoto2 capture and download

Tags: image, capture, libgphoto2, dcraw

I'm using gphoto2 capture image and download but it takes 3 or 4 seconds. I want it to only take 1 second; is it possible? Can anyone help me please? This is my code:

```
time gphoto2 --capture-image-and-download  --stdout > /dev/null
```

Which returns

```
real    0m3.584s
user    0m0.136s
sys 0m0.072s
```

Answer (score 0):

I build a photobooth with a Raspberry Pi 3 and a Canon 600D DSLR. I use the same command and display the image after all. It takes about 7 seconds and is always an issue for costumers, because they want it to be very fast.
The only solution i know is to use a camera attached directly to the graphic unit of the Raspberry and not via USB, wich does not work with a DSLR. That is the fastest way. But therefore you have lower image quality.